# ASP.NET Core Identify Auth + Angular: Login Not Working

Tags: c#, angular, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm presently developing an application with an ASP.NET Core (2.1) API server/backend and an Angular Single Page Application frontend.

For user authentication, I'm using ASP.NET Core Identity, along with several of the default methods provided within `AccountController` for login, logout, register, forgot password, etc. My Angular application accesses this API to perform these actions.

The Angular client files are hosted directly out of `wwwroot` in the ASP.NET Core application. I am hosting using IIS Express (I have tried IIS as well to no avail) under `localhost:5000`.

Authentication is configured in ASP.NET Core's `Startup` class with the following:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
    {
        config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
        config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

// Prevent API from redirecting to login or Access Denied screens (Angular handles these).
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

Register and Forgot Password both work without a hitch. The API is called and the appropriate actions are taken.

Login *appears* to work: The method is invoked within Angular:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService extends BaseService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    super(httpClient, `${config.SERVER_API_URL}/account`);
  }

  // Snip

  login(login: Login): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.httpClient.post<boolean>(`${this.actionUrl}/Login`, login)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  // Snip
}
```

The ASP.NET Core API gets the call, logs the user in, and returns success to indicate to Angular that login worked and they should proceed to redirect the user:

```
namespace ApartmentBonds.Web.Api.Account
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class AccountController : APIControllerBase
    {
        // Snip

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return Ok(true);
                }
            }

            return Ok(false);
        }

        // Snip
    }
}
```

The session cookie is created successfully, and I can see it within the browser (using Firefox Quantum in this screenshot, but have also tried in IE, in Firefox incognito, etc):

[image: Cookie]

To test, I have another API method which simply returns whether or not the calling user is signed in:

```
// Angular
isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.httpClient.get<boolean>(`${this.actionUrl}/IsLoggedIn`)
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

// ASP.NET Core API
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult IsLoggedIn()
{
    return Ok(_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User));
}
```

I make this call within the browser, **and it returns false**. (All other aspects of the site that depend on the user being logged in also show the user is not logged in -- this method is just a quick and dirty way to verify this problem.) Note that the client is correctly sending the Identity cookie along with the request:

[image: IsLoggedIn Request]

Since the only site in question here is `localhost:5000` I'm not sure why this is not working.

**Things I've tried**

- Within `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie`

  - Setting `options.Events.Cookie.Domain` to `localhost:5000` explicitly
  - Setting `options.Events.Cookie.Path` to `/api`
- Clearing all cookies and trying incognito/other browsers (to rule out other localhost site cookies potentially clobbering the request)
- Hosting the site via IIS (`localhost:8888`) after Publishing the Core Application

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have `app.UseAuthentication();` in the middleware pipeline?

Comment: What do your logs say? Does the cookie authentication handler run and does it authenticate? If not, what does it say?

Comment: @mjwills login works correctly with a static form as well as an Angular form (which in the app is just a form that submits async to the API anyway).

Comment: @juunas you win the prize. `app.UseAuthentication();` was *not* present in `Startup` anywhere (and I made the assumption that it was in there by default). I added that, and 'lo and behold it works. Post it as an answer and credit is yours.

Comment: It's important to note that your `Login` MVC action is prone to **session fixation/XSRF attacks**: a bad guy could force a victim to transparently log in under his own account and potentially steal some precious data by simply creating an auto-post HTML form containing his credentials and pointing to your vulnerable action. If you absolutely want to use cookies with your API-like actions, consider adding some antiforgery to mitigate that.

Comment: @Pinpoint thanks for pointing that out. We've since added Antiforgery validation to the Login method and configured the application to use Antiforgery in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for authentication handlers to run on the request, you need `app.UseAuthentication();` in the middleware pipeline (before middleware that requires it like MVC).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. That'll teach me to assume that the `Startup` file has all the auth bits it needs out of the box!

Answer (score 0):

This is a longshot, but maybe the token needs: "Bearer " (with the space) in front of the actual token.

Comment: This is not applicable to this issue... you are referring to JWT Token auth... this post is about using ASP.NET Identity auth with cookies... completely different thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use **User** property from controller when you are using **AllowAnonymousAttribute**.

Try to do request to some authorize endpoint. If you are not sign in, then you will get status code 401(Unathorized).